# Has Ubuntu 16.04 failled to fetch repository information or is my computer software up to date? (different case)

Tags: updates, 16.04, repository

On running **Software Update** it says `Failed to download repository information` but when I click on `Settings->Close`... it refreshes and says the software on this computer is up to date.

What should I believe? How can I fix this and prevent it from happening again?

History: Repository info had failed to download in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS too. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in hopes of fixing the problem... I have selected the nearest Ubuntu server. Internet is working just fine. Also the urls mentioned below do not exit.

This is what the terminal says:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

P.S. I think my problem is a little different (1st paragraph) from the other questions and I couldn't comment on those due to lack of reputation. If you still think its a duplicate please just let me know and I'll remove it ASAP. Please don't mark this in anyway to get negative reputation.

Comment: See this: question: [Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603058/failed-to-fetch-http-extras-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-dists-vivid/603060#603060)
and this email [Fwd: Please retire extras.ubuntu.com](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2015-January/002063.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

i've also been struggling to add the extras repository...
it's just not there...

anyone who's saying it's working must be lying or must be interpreting the data wrong on his screen...
you can check it yourself; in your webbrowser go to http://extras.ubuntu.com
you'll get the root directory of the repository on your screen... the first thing ubuntu will do is go into dists and check for the correct version info...
as you can all see; there is no xenial directory available (as of yet).

and as long as there is not xenial directory, we won't be able to use the extras repository under 16.04 without possible flaws.
you COULD use the version for 14.04 (trusty tahr).
what you need to do then is change the info in your "software and updates" settings; edit the extras repository and change the line to let it looklike this;
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
now there won't be an error when you update your repositories (or do apt update) but if you use software out of this repository it could end up damaging your system as it is designed for an older system; so i would definitely not recommend it; only if you really need some apps that are in there of which you are sure that they don't mess up the system, then it'd say go for it (let's say apps like a game or a paint program; but don't get any system tools out of it because they could really harm your system (ie things could've changed between trusty and xenial, and those old tools don't know that; they make changes according to the trusty settings but your computer is expecting xenial settings; a lot of things stay the same between xenial and trusty, but some things have changed too. if you modify one of those changed ones with outdated software you could render your system useless (constant crashing or even data loss in the worst case... If you really know what youre doing, then go ahead off course!)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem after some search i found out that in older lts versions of Ubuntu it helped to change the server to main-server.
I tried this out and somehow I got the same error report but the Updates were found and able to install , a little strange but it kind of works. 
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In my 14.04LTS sources.list there is a comment on the `extra` sources:

```
##This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
```

Apparently those packages are not in 16.06LTS `extra`. Probably the relevant packages have been moved to the normal sources.

I commented out the lines below that and run the install again.